# identify a machine not by using IP

Tags: c#, java, c++, security

Suppose I'm programming a game and I want the option of banning people from it after violating the terms. I can ban them per account, I can also ban their IP but it's not going to ban them from my game forever. They will just have to create a new account and change their IP.

Is there something like a machine-ID that is unique for every machine in the world? If there is, is it possible to read it using a program language? Is it possible for the user to change this machine-ID?

Comment: No. Unless you're running code on that user's machine, there is absolutely NO way to 100% reliably identify a machine - all you get on your end is an IP addresss. You don't get a MAC address, you don't get a system serial number, you don't get a cpu serial number etc... All you get is an IP.

Comment: how does the users run the game? is it web based? app? specific OS installation? platform, etc..

Comment: The user running the game on his PC, lets say it's a window application. ofcourse it uses internet network to communicate with the server. @MarcB Is there absolutely no way to any CPU serial number? no MAC address? OS serial?

Comment: OS Serial - users will not share for sure. MAC address can be worked around - it's unique but will not solve your purpose.

Comment: MAC addresses are not available unless the machine is in the same ethernet segment as you are. You're limited to what's sent in tcp packets, and by default the only two identifiable bits of that packet are the IP address and remote port, neither of which is useful for identifiying a particular user. That's why you'd have to run code on their machine, so you can get the ID data that's available ONLY on the user's machine. Since they're unlikely to go "sure, go ahead and rummage around my system for ID info so you can block", you're stuck.

Comment: I don't see where OP said it's a browser game.

Comment: @SuyashKhandwe what? do you know how much OS serial number are equal because of "ilegal" copy?

Comment: Most of the ways the user can "hack". Some requires less work and knowledge, some more advanced ones. I think your best bet is to use a mix of the serials you found in the user computer. Anyway for serious scenarios you link the account with a unique physical person by some user provided information. So hardly the user can simple create other account.

Comment: use a "reputation system" like SO, and no one will create a new account and start again with the desperately hunt of new points... :)))

Comment: I just changed my MachineGuid and restarted my win8, nothing strange happened. PC still activated.

Answer (score 1):

**Bulletproof solution**?
I would say **no solution** will be `100% secure`, even with huge invested money..
What you can do, is to make it as hard as possible for normal users, and this way minimize the `cheaters`.

You could make a `hash id` of the pc `machine id` + `the mac address` + `the motherboard id` + `the harddisk id`, etc. But a clever cracker/hacker could get around this. I mean take a look at companies like Microsoft that uses millions in making a secure way and still people can get around the activation in some way... ;)

---

In windows there is a `hardware id`, that you might be intrested in.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Cryptography\MachineGuid
```

---

Take a look at WMI too, there are examples of how to use it with c++

**Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)** is a set of extensions to the Windows Driver Model that provides an operating system interface through which instrumented components.

see [WMI c++ exmaples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: it can be easily altered, isnt it?

Comment: I can not say 100%, but almost, all solutions will have a way to crack. You can only make it harder. I dont think many ppl would bother go in and risk to change the guid, which might fail the windows license/activation (not sure about this but maybe someone else might give a comment about this)

Comment: What about sending different guid with another application similar to what OP's client does without changing that value.

Answer (score 0):

How about hard disk serial number which you can get in WMI [Win32_DiskDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = null;

try
{
    searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive"); 

    foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SerialNumber: {0}", queryObj["SerialNumber"]);
        queryObj.Dispose();
    }
}
finally
{
    if (searcher != null)
        searcher.Dispose();
}
```